# Is it possible to have a matrix with eigenvalues that cannot be constructed from a finite number of basic arithmetic operations, and nth roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, galois-theory

For example, a characteristic polynomial $ p(\lambda) = \lambda^5 - \lambda -1 $ has the root 1.167304..., but this number cannot be written as a finite number of arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) and nth roots. However, is it even possible to have a matrix with such a characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Let $\lambda _1, \lambda _2, \lambda _3$ be the roots of the polynomial and consider $\text{diag}(\lambda _1, \lambda _2, \lambda _3)$?

Comment: Yes, it is always possible! look at [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for construction.

Comment: The companion matrix is a bit nicer, since you don't have the problem of the roots of the characteristic polynomial being in your field.

Comment: @achille hui, that's what I was looking for -- thanks!